# VBScript file writing doesn't work. What is the problem?

Tags: file, vbscript, file-writing

I use the example code on this website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/314cz14s(v=vs.84)

I placed the code inside the main sub: between Sub Main() and End Sub

The file "c:\testfile.txt" isn't created when I run the script.

What is the problem?

Comment: did you forget to `Call` your Main sub routine?

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem. I have never used VBScript before and thought that the Sub Main() works like the main function in other programming languages.

But there's still a problem with this code when it comes to reading. Error: object required: 'Document'.

Comment: Replace the line `Document.Write TextLine & "<br />"` with `WScript.Echo TextLine` (bad mistake in the MS example code..). Also, run the script using CScript.exe, not Wscript.exe otherwise the `WScript.Echo` command will show a messagebox for every single line it outputs.